# F# - Determine if an argument is a function

Tags: f#

```
let isFunction ``functionOrValue`` = 
    ???

let aFunction p1 p2 ... = <code>
let aValue = 5 // or obj() or whatever type

isFunction aFunction // true
isFunction aValue // false
```

How to check in a function body if a passed argument is a function?

Or in other words, what would **isFunction** code look like?

Comment: Check out if this is usable: https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-reflection-fsharptype.html#IsFunction

Comment: I like that. Didn't know it existed. This is probably better than my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `FSharpType` type from `FSharp.Reflection` to find out whether a type is an F# function (or another interesting standard F# type):

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let isFunction functionOrValue = 
    FSharpType.IsFunction(functionOrValue.GetType())

let aFunction p1 p2 = p1 + p2
let aValue = 5 

isFunction aFunction // true
isFunction aValue // false
isFunction null // throws exception because of `null.GetType()`
```

That said, doing anything with a value of type `obj` that is an F# function under the cover will be tricky and you'll have to do everything using reflection, so it may be worth considering if there are other possible designs for the thing that you are actually trying to do. If it is inherently dynamic, then reflection makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend this, but the following should work:

```ml
let isFunction (obj : obj) =
    let baseType = obj.GetType().BaseType
    if isNull baseType then false
    else baseType.Name.StartsWith("FSharpFunc")
```

Test:

```ml
let aFunction p1 p2 = ()
let aValue = 5 // or obj() or whatever type

isFunction aFunction |> printfn "%A" // true
isFunction aValue |> printfn "%A" // false
```